# How to join three SQL tables such that we can get information from the third?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the three tables - Employee, Location and Department

```
Employee:
EmployeeID
Name
DeptID

Department:
DepartmentID
DeptName
LocID

Location:
LocationID 
LocationName

Employee.DeptID is a foreign key to Department.DepartmentID. 
Department.LocID is a foreign key to Location.LocationID
```

How would one find the LocationName of a particular employee? E.g. how would we find the LocationName of EmployeeID 1234? We would have to get his/her DeptID, then match it with the Department.DepartmentID, and then match that Department.LocID to Location.LocationID and then get the LocationName of that LocID. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
select employee.name, employee.employeeID, location.name from employee join department on department.departmentID = employee.departmentID join location on location.locationID = department.locID
```

If you want to restrict the employees displayed you can add a where clause:

```
where employee.employeeID = 1234
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)